# How to stream my webcam in flutter gui from flask server?

Tags: flutter, flask

I want to see my webcam-stream on my web-gui. But the Code I'm using isnt working.
Any suggestions?

What am I doing wrong. I dont get any picture out of it. But the server is sending a picture. Or a stream.

Any suggestions are welcome.

You can see my code below.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
import cv2
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

def generate_frames():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while True:
        success, frame = cap.read()
        if not success:
            break
        else:
            ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
            frame = buffer.tobytes()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')
        # Warte für 5 Sekunden, bevor das nächste Bild gesendet wird
        time.sleep(5)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(generate_frames(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:typed_data';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Webcam Viewer'),
        ),
        body: WebcamView(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class WebcamView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WebcamViewState createState() => _WebcamViewState();
}

class _WebcamViewState extends State<WebcamView> {
  String imageUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/video_feed';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Image.network(imageUrl),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you're trying to display the stream using an Image.network widget. However, Image.network is not suitable for displaying a video stream because it's designed for static images. To display a live stream, you can use the iframe element if you're targeting the web. In Flutter, you can use the HtmlElementView to embed an iframe.